How to make the filter apply to all files in the folder?
I have a document library with few metadata columns. There are several folders, sub folders and files. The files have the metadata columns (example: choice column, managed metadata columns, etc) filled with information.
At the top folder level, in the default view, when I click on the filter icon, then it allows me only to filter contents that are currently displayed. I mean - it doesn't show me the values of the files inside the folder/subfolders.
Also, the filter seems to be working only on the current folder contents. It doesn't filter subfolder/files.
Is the filter applicable only to the current displayed items?
How to make the filter show values of files? And how to make the filter applicable to files in folder/subfolders?

How's going today? Do you have further concerns regarding this issue? Please feel free to talk with us if you have other questions.

To apply a filter to all files within a folder in SharePoint Online, you typically need to utilize views or search queries. Here's how you can achieve this:
Using Views:You can create a view in SharePoint Online document libraries that filters files based on certain criteria. Here's how you can do it:
Navigate to your document library in SharePoint Online.
Click on the "Library" tab in the ribbon.
Click on "Create View" and choose the type of view you want to create (e.g., Standard View).
In the view creation form, you can specify filter criteria under the "Filter" section. You can filter files based on metadata columns, file properties, or other criteria.
Save the view, and it will be available for users to apply when browsing the document library.
Using Search Queries:You can also use search queries to filter files within a folder in SharePoint Online. This approach is more flexible and powerful, as it allows you to construct complex queries using Keyword Query Language (KQL). Here's how you can do it:
Use the search box in the document library and enter your search query. For example, you can search for files with a specific metadata property or file name.
Refine your search query using KQL operators such as AND, OR, and NOT to construct complex filters.
SharePoint Online will return search results that match your query, and you can further refine them using the search refiners available in the search results page.
By using views or search queries, you can effectively filter files within a folder in SharePoint Online based on your specific criteria. Choose the approach that best fits your requirements and user experience preferences.

I tried the view approach. I have a nested folder structure. When I apply the filter then it doesn't show me the files inside the folder/subfolders.
